# WTForms File Validation Limitations

Tags: python, cherrypy, wtforms

I would like some advise on weather I should perform file validation for a CSV file in WTForms. The user story is that a user will select a file to upload, select the type of operation to perform and then submit. Right now we are validating the uploaded file with a helper function in the controller. A colleague suggested I use WTForms to perform the file validation.  The CSV file will have different validation requirements based on the op type that the user selects. So my question is, is WTForms a good tool for this type of validation? If so would you have any suggestions on an approach. Currently I'm blocked on how to pass what the user selects to the file validator.

Here's my current implementation:

```
# Controller
op_type = params['op_type']
file_info = params['input_file']
errors = ValidateFile(file_info, op_type)
if errors:
  # do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know about WTForms until now, so I checked the [crash course](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crash_course.html) in the docs, and I have to say this looks pretty neat and furthermore I think it is very simple to achieve what you want. Why don't just give it a try?

Basic example for a wtforms.fields.FileField that you will need to use in your case:

```
class UploadForm(Form):
    image        = FileField(u'Image File', [validators.regexp(u'^[^/\\]\.jpg$')])
    description  = TextAreaField(u'Image Description')

    def validate_image(form, field):
        if field.data:
            field.data = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9_.-]', '_', field.data)

def upload(request):
    form = UploadForm(request.POST)
    if form.image.data:
        image_data = request.FILES[form.image.name].read()
        open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, form.image.data), 'w').write(image_data)
```

found [here](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#basic-fields).

EDIT:

If you want to do the validation depending on your radio input button, the only reasonable solution would be to access the post variable of your radio button from within the validator function. Not sure about the syntax, but try something like this:

```
    def validate_file(form, field):
        if field.data:
            radio_x = form.radio_x.data
            if radio_x == 'on':
                # your validation
                if error:
                    raise ValidationError('Your input is invalid!')
```

Feel free to improve my answer.

Comment: So my issue is that the validation depends on which radio button the user selects. Not sure how to set up the form for that.

Comment: @Dan if I get your question right then I don't think it is about the setup of the form but about how you implement the validation in python. I edited my answer.